# Windows 10 - Cancel Shutdown/Logoff while in progress

Tags: windows-10

Is there any keyboard shortcut or method that will halt a windows shutdown or logoff while it is in progress?

I am not talking about a scheduled shutdown, but one that is user-initiated.

Comment: Not once it has started

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by "in progress" you're in the timeout period, you can use the command line option `shutdown /a` to abort a shutdown/restart. Use `shutdown /?` to list possible options.

If however you're on the 'Windows is restarting' screen, as far as I know you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm talking about the latter